# Setting up PostGIS on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, postgis

I followed this manual:
http://www.paolocorti.net/2008/01/30/installing-postgis-on-ubuntu/
I installed using aptitude:

```
postgis
postgresql-8.4-postgis
```

but there is no script lwpostgis.sql in the `/usr/share/postgresql-8.4-postgis/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use "/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis.sql" instead of "/usr/share/postgresql-8.2-postgis/lwpostgis.sql".

Comment: i have not this file but i have "/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sql" is that normally? that file i must to use instead of "/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/spatial_ref_sys.sql"

Comment: No, you need use postgis.sql first, then spatial_ref_sys.sql. To find postgis.sql: dpkg -L postgresql-8.4-postgis | grep "postgis.sql"

Comment: on ubuntu 10 i found the file in
"/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis/postgis-1.5/postgis.sql"